# How Does Whonix Keep The User Anonymous?

Tags: security, privacy, whonix

How does Whonix Linux keep a user secure?

I am aware of how it works in terms of the Gateway which uses Tor, but how does the Whonix workstation ensure nothing is logged, or stored, on the OS and no fingerprinting can be done on the user who was using the workstation session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how does the Whonix workstation ensure nothing is logged, or stored, on the OS

It doesn't. [Whonix is not amnesic.](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Warning#Whonix_is_not_amnesic); [There is no Whonix Live version yet.](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/FAQ#Will_there_be_a_Whonix_Live_CD_or_DVD.3F); [There is no substitute for Whonix's lack of an Amnesic feature](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_there_a_substitute_for_Whonix.27s_lack_of_an_Amnesic_feature_.2F_Live_CD.2FDVD.3F_Forensics.3F)

> and no fingerprinting can be done on the user who was using the workstation session?

See also documentation about [Fingerprint](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Fingerprint) as well as technical information [Whonix's Protocol-Leak-Protection and Fingerprinting-Protection](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Whonix%27s_Protocol-Leak-Protection_and_Fingerprinting-Protection).

Full disclosure: 
I am maintainer of Whonix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about whonix but I know tails stays anonymous by never using the harddisk and only using the RAM to run and store data. When it quits the RAM is erased. Maybe its similar to that.

Comment: No, Whonix does save the state across reboots.

Comment: to whoever downvoted my answer I tried to make it a comment but my reputation wouldn't allow me.